# How can I create a bidimentional array with tuple elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how can I crate a bidimensional array whose rows and columns are elements from tuples.

```
n = len(states)
m = len(rating)

rating = "Mala", "Regular", "Buena", "Muy buena", "Excelente"

states = "Buenos Aires", "Catamarca", "Chaco", "Chubut", "Córdoba", "Corrientes", "Entre Ríos", "Formosa", "Jujuy", "La Pampa", "La Rioja", "Mendoza", "Misiones", "Neuquén", "Río Negro", "Salta", "San Juan", "San Luis", "Santa Cruz", "Santa Fe", "Santiago del Estero", "Tierra del Fuego", "Tucumán"

def createMatrix(n, m):
    mat = [None] * n
    for f in range(n):
        mat[f] = [None] * m
    return mat
```

I need to upgrade the bidimensional array creation function to create a matrix whose rows and columns are the elements from the tuples, and the elements of the matrix are zeros.

Comment: Try numpy arrays. They are accessed like this: arr[x, y] and can be help for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to create a matrix where elements are all zeros, you can something like this.

```
import numpy
numpy.zeros((m, n)).tolist()
```

Comment: If you create a list like that, the outer list will contain copies of the same inner list and hence updates of the form `x[0][0]` will actually update every `x[i][0]` for `0 <= i < m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=0, columns=rating, index=states)
```

Then you can use e.g. `df.loc['Buenos Aires', 'Regular']` to access the corresponding item.